# How to create a rectangle in a rectangle?

Tags: java, swing, drawrect, graphics2d, paintcomponent

In my paintComponent, I have drawRect, which draws a single rectangle. However, I want to make the outline of the rectangle thicker but I don't know how. So I thought of making another rectangle inside the existing one. I tried putting another drawRect but the rectangle isn't in the center.

Thanks for those who'll help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(6));
```

---

The argument passed to the `paintComponent(Graphics)` method of a Swing component should actually be a `Graphics2D` instance.  It can be cast to one.

See this example in which 3 strokes are layered.

[image: Stroke It]

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

class StrokeIt {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                StrokePanel sp = new StrokePanel();
                sp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,100));
                sp.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, sp);
            }
        });
    }
}

class StrokePanel extends JPanel {

    int pad = 12;

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;

        g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
        g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(10));
        g2d.drawRect( 0+pad, 0+pad,
            getWidth()-(2*pad), getHeight()-(2*pad) );

        g2d.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(6));
        g2d.drawRect( 0+pad, 0+pad,
            getWidth()-(2*pad), getHeight()-(2*pad) );

        g2d.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
        g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2));
        g2d.drawRect( 0+pad, 0+pad,
            getWidth()-(2*pad), getHeight()-(2*pad) );
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't this for Graphics2D only? Do you need to put super.paintComponent for Graphics2D?

Comment: Thank you, I have successfully made it.